# SQLAlchemy 0.7.8 raw string queries issue with params

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Pyramid application and I need to use 'format' paramstyle. For example:

```
DBSession.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = %s;', email)
```

This in theory should work, but I get sqla error:

```
('SQL Error!', AttributeError("'list' object has no attribute 'keys'",))
```

even while `email` is string and not list. I tried using tuple but I get the same error (but instead of "list" it says "tuple").

I use `pg8000` as DB driver.

How else should I supply params to the query?

Comment: When you get a python error, please include the full traceback.

Answer (score 8):

By using the `execute` method of the session, the parameters handling is done by SQLAlchemy, thus you need something like:

```
DBSession.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email;', {'email': email})
```

However, if you use the `execute` method of the engine instead, then the parameters handling is done by the underlying DB-API, which is pg8000 in this case, e.g.

```
DBSession.bind.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = %s;', email)
```

Anyway, I always stick with the former, to have a consistent way to handle parameters across different drivers / databases.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through http://pybrary.net/pg8000/dbapi.html#pg8000.dbapi.CursorWrapper.execute it looks like `pg8000.dbapi.paramstyle` is set to `named` thus it is expecting a mapping which would look like:

```
DBSession.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = %(email)s', {'email': email})
```

It appears you want to set `paramstyle` to `pyformat` which looks like the most flexible option - allowing a sequence or mapping (or maybe just to `format` if not required).

Comment: Yeah, but default sqlalchemy `paramstyle` is set to `format` (I also tryied to set it with
    `engine.dialect.paramstyle = 'format'`
and I'm not sure if there is any other way to change `paramstyle` when using sqlalchemy.

I would really like to user any other `paramstyle` but we need to use same text queries in couple separate applications, and rest of them use `format`.

Comment: @MarekSzwalkiewicz What is `pg8000.dbapi.paramstyle` currently set to? (Apparently the default should be `format`)

Comment: I'm not sure if I have access to `pg8000` objects trough sqlalchemy, I'm setting everything up with `engine_from_config` - so I'm afraid that I can't check it with pshell, but by default it is set to `format` and should not be overwritten by sqlalchemy.